# Change div according to dropdown boxes selected

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

Trying to display only `<div>` that matches the dropdown boxes selected in the form.

The form gets generated using a Form class, and options are in tables in the database (`race`, `class`). In the end looks like this:

```
<form action="" method="post" name="create" target="_top">
    <fieldset>
        <ul class="create">
            <li>
                <label class="label" for="character_name">Character Name:</label>
                <input class="text" type="text" name="character_name" id="character_name" />
            </li>
            <li>
                <label class="label" for="character_gender">Gender:</label>
                <select class="character_gender select" name="character_gender" id="character_gender">
                    <option class="option" value="1">Female</option>
                    <option class="option" value="2">Male</option>
                </select>
            </li>
            <li>
                <label class="label" for="character_race">Character Race:</label>
                <select class="character_race select" name="character_race" id="character_race">
                    <option class="option" value="1">Goblin</option>
                    <option class="option" value="2">Human</option>
                    <option class="option" value="3">Undead</option>
                </select>
            </li>
            <li>
                <label class="label" for="character_class">Character Class:</label>
                <select class="character_class select" name="character_class" id="character_class">
                    <option class="option" value="1">Warrior</option>
                    <option class="option" value="2">Wizard</option>
                </select>
            </li>
            <li>
                <input class="submit-create-character" type="submit" name="create_character" value="Create" />
            </li>
        </ul>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

My controller calls in the Avatar, CharacterClass, Race classes.

My `avatar` table has columns that store the IDs to the `race.id`, and `class.id` table.id_column's.

```
# Get all the avatars in the `avatars` table.
$avatars=$avatar_obj->getAllAvatars();

foreach($avatars as $avatar)
{
    # Get the image information from the database, and set them to data members.
    $avatar_obj->getThisImage($avatar->image_id);
    # Set the Image object to a variable.
    $image_obj=$avatar_obj->getImageObj();
    # Set the image file name to a variable.
    $image_file_name=$image_obj->getFileName();

    # Get the class info from the database and set the data members.
    $class_obj->getThisCharacterClass($avatar->class_id);
    # Get the race info from the database and set the data members.
    $race_obj->getThisRace($avatar->race_id);

    echo '<div class="class-info">',
        '<div class="avatar-box">',
            '<img src="'.IMAGES_PATH.$image_file_name.'" alt="'.$image_obj->getTitle().'" />',
        '</div>';
        echo $race_obj->getDescription().'<br>';
        echo $class_obj->getDescription();
    echo '</div>';
}
```

This displays a bunch of `<div>`'s:

```
<div class="class-info">
    <div class="avatar-box"><img src="Female.Goblin.Warrior.gif" alt="Female Warrior" /></div>
    Goblin description.<br>
    Warrior Description
</div>
<div class="class-info">
    <div class="avatar-box"><img src="Male.Goblin.Warrior.gif" alt="Male Warrior" /></div>
    Goblin description.<br>
    Wizard Description
</div>
<div class="class-info">
    <div class="avatar-box"><img src="Female.Human.Warrior.gif" alt="Female Warrior" /></div>
    Human description.<br>
    Warrior Description
</div>
<div class="class-info">
    <div class="avatar-box"><img src="Male.Human.Warrior.gif" alt="Male Warrior" /></div>
    Human description.<br>
    Wizard Description
</div>
<div class="class-info">
    <div class="avatar-box"><img src="Female.Undead.Warrior.gif" alt="Female Warrior" /></div>
    Undead description.<br>
    Warrior Description
</div>
<div class="class-info">
    <div class="avatar-box"><img src="Male.Undead.Warrior.gif" alt="Male Warrior" /></div>
    Undead description.<br>
    Wizard Description
</div>
```

(And a lot more)

I am stuck at this point. I am not sure how to figure out the jQuery to hide/show the correct `<div>`.

Comment: What's wrong with the gender select?

Comment: Actually, nothing. I don't even need the gender_id in the `avatar` table, I have the `image_id`. I was overthinking it. Just need the jQuery to make it all work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't well written by any means: http://jsfiddle.net/dz5gh7wo/2/

(**UPDATE**: slightly more maintainable example http://jsfiddle.net/dz5gh7wo/7/)

What you want to do is to add an on change event listener that fires when the input fields change.

```
$('#character_race, #character_gender, #character_class').on('change', buildCharacter);
```

Here I added it to all of your fields in a very sloppy way, but this is just for educational purposes. It calls a `buildCharacter` function.

Then we define that function.

```
var buildCharacter = function() {
    var charRace = $('#character_race :selected').text(),
        charGender = $('#character_gender :selected').text(),
        charClass = $('#character_class :selected').text(),
        cssStr = charGender+'-'+charRace+'-'+charClass;
    $('.class-info').hide();
    $('.'+cssStr.toLowerCase()).show();
};
```

You will want to hide all of your unused class divs with some CSS

```css
.class-info {
  display: none
}
```

and finally call build character on page load

`buildCharacter();`

You will need classes on each of your character displays so that you can show and hide them at will.

`female-goblin-warrior`